# Include fields from related tables

Tags: ef-core-2.1, audit.net

I'm using EF with DotNet Core 2.1 in my application. The application deals with data in multiple related and with FK interconnected tables.

I need audit logging data only changes to one table. However, my problem is, the table I need to audit log has quite some FK and for each of these I would like to log the FK itself and a field from the related table.

Let me try illustrate what I'm about - let's suppose this is my model:

```
public class Blog {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Url { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty ("Blog")]
  public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

  public Blog() {
    Posts = new Collection<Post> ();
  }
}
...
[AuditInclude]
public class Post
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int BlogId { get; set; }
  public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

As said, I'd like audit logging only changes to one entity - let's say it is a `Post` - here is an audit class:

```
public class Audit_Post : IAudit {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }

  public int BlogId { get; set; }
  public string Blog { get; set; }    // <- I need populating this from Blog.Name

  [StringLength (64)]
  public string AuditUsername { get; set; }
  public DateTime AuditDt { get; set; }
  public string AuditAction { get; set; }

  public Audit_Manufacturer () { }
}
```

And this is how I set up audit logging in my `startup.cs -> ConfigureService()`:

```
...
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup ()
  .UseEntityFramework (ef => ef
    .AuditTypeExplicitMapper (m => m
      .Map<Post, Audit_Post> ((d, al) => {
        al.Blog = d.Blog?.Name;    // !! This doesn't work
      })
      .AuditEntityAction<IAudit> ((evt, entry, auditEntity) => {
        Object val;
        var gotVal = evt.CustomFields.TryGetValue ("AuditUsername", out val);
        string username = null;
        if (gotVal && val is string)
          username = val as string;
        else
          username = "<anonymous>";
        auditEntity.AuditDt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        auditEntity.AuditUsername = username;
        auditEntity.AuditAction = entry.Action;
      })
    )
  );
```

**question**: Is it possible at all to get and audit log data from dependant table (one-to-many) relation?

Beside the mentioned issue, I'm also bumped in an off-topic one, which is - if I forget updating the DB with the migration for initialising the `Audit_Posts` table and I'm doing operations on `Posts` table, the data get stored to the later even if audit logs fail to get written (UnitOfWork save exception). Is there a flag to `AuditDbContext` that would make it run in the same transaction as the original query?

Answer (score 1):

As @thepirat000 pointed out, it is enough to guarantee all related items being present in the `DbContext` memory. This means:

- **INSERT** Just before doing `context.Posts.Add(item)` do a query to all related items such as `context.Blogs.Find(item.BlogId)`.
- **UPDATE** When retrieving the `Post`, do it with `.Include(d => d.Blog)` + other related items.
- **DELETE** When retrieving the `Post`, do it with `.Include(d => d.Blog)` + other related items.

An additional important thing that was causing me troubles is the layout of my Audit table. The issue was I reused the same property name in Audit table with a different type - in the original table the property `Blog` was a relationship property, whiles in the audit table it was a string. This caused errors in conversion from one to the other model.

```
[AuditInclude]
public class Post
{
  ...
  [Required]
  public int BlogId { get; set; }
  public Blog Blog { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Just rename it to something else like:

```
public class Audit_Post
{
  ...
  public int BlogId { get; set; }
  public string BlogName { get; set; }
  ...
}
...
// and in startup.cs use ...
...
.Map<Post, Audit_Post> ((d, al) => {
    al.BlogName = d.Blog?.Name;
  })
...
```

Regarding the 2nd issue - running audit inside transactions. I decided not to use it for now. I'll get covered the described case with tests.

Maybe a suggestion for future development of the package - it would be nice to have mentioned cases covered easily - I mean, transitive properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine if you `Include` the `Blog` property when retrieving the `Post` entity, for example:

```
using (var context = new BlogsContext())
{
    var post = context.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Blog)  // Important, otherwise post.Blog will be NULL
        .First();

    post.Content += " adding this";
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you can't include the Blog entity because any reason, you could do the query on the mapping, but you will need to use a lower level overload on the `Map` method, like this:

```
.Map<Post, PostAudit>((ev, entry, postAudit) =>
{
    var entryEf = entry.GetEntry();

    var post = entryEf.Entity as Post;
    var dbContext = entryEf.Context as BlogsContext;

    // Get the blog related
    var blog = dbContext.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == post.BlogId);

    postAudit.Blog = blog?.Name;
})
```

Regarding the other question, currently there is no built-in mechanism to rollback your database changes when the audit saving fails, but maybe you try with the `AuditDbContext` [overrides](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#overrides)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I already tried using `Include()`, but without success. I thought this is due to the fact it is not a `select`, `update` or `delete`.
This is what I tried in my `PostRepository -> Add(Post item)`: `context.Posts.Include(d => d.Blog).Add(item)`, but this resulted in an invalid operation as `IIncludableQueryable<Post, Blog>` doesn't contain a defintion for `Add()`. I'm investigating further on this.
The other solution you suggested would probably work - I'm going to try it right now. I'm just wondering if this will be way more expensive as will result in +1 query.

Comment: With the `Map<>((ev, entry, postAudit) => { ... })` code I can use only async methods on the `dbContext.Blogs`, but the mapping isn't async, therefore I cannot await the result - I'm still investigating why <<< I'm feeling like a newbie :)